# How to scrapRSS link in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to gather some data from RSS Feed link. I have 4 RSS link i want to loop onto all those link and grab the data into single Page. I have one link in feed variable but i have no idea how to add few more either in Array or some another way

Another link: https://www.kijiji.ca/rss-srp-rideshare-carpool/ontario/rideshare/k0c5l9004
https://www.kijiji.ca/rss-srp-rideshare-carpool/ontario/rideshare/page-2/k0c5l9004

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var feed = "https://www.kijiji.ca/rss-srp-rideshare-carpool/ontario/rideshare/k0c5l9004";

    $.ajax(feed, {
        accepts:{
            xml:"application/rss+xml"
        },
        dataType:"xml",
        success:function(data) {
                $(data).find("item").each(function () {
                var el = $(this);
                var titleU= el.find("title").text();
                console.log(titleU);        
            });

        }   
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you just loop through the feeds like this?

```
var feeds = ["https://www.kijiji.ca/rss-srp-rideshare-carpool/ontario/rideshare/k0c5l9004", "https://www.kijiji.ca/rss-srp-rideshare-carpool/ontario/rideshare/k0c5l9004", "https://www.kijiji.ca/rss-srp-rideshare-carpool/ontario/rideshare/page-2/k0c5l9004"];

feeds.forEach(feed => $.ajax(feed, .....));
```